# Chaining JavaScript Promises that include nested AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm looking to replace some of my existing code with JavaScript Promises and I just want to confirm that I'm not doing it wrong (or maybe there are better ways). I'm using the [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) library.

What I have are three functions that I've updated to use JavaScript Promises (what was previously a nested, callback-ey mess). The functions are actually supposed to have dual modes i.e. I can use them like regular functions and have them return a result, or I could chain them together.

```
function func_1()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(condition)
        {
            resolve('1');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('start');
            resolve(ajaxRequest(url));
        }
    });
}

function func_2(data)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(condition)
        {
            resolve('2');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(data.response);
            resolve(ajaxRequest(url));
        }
    });
}

function func_3(data)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(condition)
        {
            resolve('3');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(data.response);
            resolve(ajaxRequest(url));
        }
    });
}

func_1().then(func_2).then(func_3).then(function(data){});
```

The `if` is to check whether data is cached in localStorage/sessionStorage, and if so the function just returns the result. However, in circumstances where I am unsure if the values have been cached (e.g. first run of the script), then I plan to chain them and then have each subsequent function persist the result from its preceeding one to localStorage/sessionStorage (hence the `promise` chain on the last line). The final `then` gives me an opportunity to persist the data from `func_3`.

Based on the tests I have run, everything seems to be working ok, but I was just wondering if this was the best way of doing this? And how do I handle the AJAX errors that could happen on one or more of the 3 listed functions?

**Note**: My `AjaxRequest` function also uses the same Promise mechanism and 'resolves' a full XHR on success, and 'rejects' the same full XHR on failure/error.

**EDIT**

After a tip from @Bergi, I've updated the code to look like this (and it works just as well):

```
function func_1()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return Promise.resolve('1');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('start');
        return ajaxRequest(url);
    }
}

function func_2(data)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return Promise.resolve('2');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(data.response);
        return ajaxRequest(url);
    }
}

function func_3(data)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return Promise.resolve('3');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(data.response);
        return ajaxRequest(url);
    }
}

func_1().then(func_2).then(func_3).then(function(data){})['catch'](function(err){console.log(err)});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> everything seems to be working ok, but I was just wondering if this was the best way of doing this?

You should never really need to use the `Promise` constructor except on the lowest level (i.e. when promisifying that ajax request). Your functions should simply be written like this:

```
function func_1() {
    if (condition) {
        return Promise.resolve('1');
    } else {
        console.log('start');
        retrun ajaxRequest(url);
    }
}
```

Strictly speaking, the `func_2` and `func_3` might even do `return '2'`, the `then` method for which they are used as callbacks can cope with that. Of course it is cleaner to always return a promise object.

> And how do I handle the AJAX errors that could happen on one or more of the 3 listed functions?

Pass a second function to `then`, or use `catch`. This callback will get called when the promise is rejected, and should handle the exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks better the way you've done it and it works just as well. However, the `catch` I added (please see my edit) stops on the specific error e.g. if `func_2` ajax has an error, it doesn't complete the chain. Is this normal behaviour and can I change things?!

Comment: Yes, exceptions "bubble". If `func2` rejects the promise, the "success handler" `func3` will not get called, but that next promise does get immediately rejected as well. To change this behaviour, you need to catch the exception right after `func2`, and the handler needs to return `data` that then continue the chain and get passed to `func3`.

Comment: Thanks. Please could you post a quick code sample for how I can achieve that behaviour?

Comment: `func1().then(func2).catch(function(err){ /* handle any errs from func1 or func2 */ return mockdata; }).then(func3).then(allDone)`